# Make a button block when in small device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I need to have my button occupy the whole width when the view is small such as viewing it on a mobile phone. This is what I have so far...

**Large Device**
[image]

**Medium Device**
[image]

**Small Device**

[image]

On medium to small device, I need to have the button take up the whole block. I am not using any custom css yet. I'm just using the bootstrap default. Please see my code below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header class="p-3 bg-dark text-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
      <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-white text-decoration-none">
        <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32" role="img" aria-label="Bootstrap"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
      </a>

      <ul class="nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-secondary">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">About</a></li>
      </ul>

      <form class="col-12 col-lg-auto mb-3 mb-lg-0 me-lg-3" style="display:flex; align-items:inherit;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-dark" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username">
        <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-dark" placeholder="Pasword" aria-label="Password">
        <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-outline-light" style="margin-left: 1rem!important;">Login</button>
      </form>



      <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
        <button class="btn btn-primary me-md-2" type="button">Button</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
      </div>

      @*
      <div class="text-end d-sm-block gap-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" style="width:100%; display:block;">
                            Sign-up
                        </button>
      </div>*@
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.... The only change is adding `d-grid gap-2` to the Div which houses your button. You may have to edit the number `2` to get your fully desired effect. With this you can probably remove the `style=` from your button too.

```
<div class="text-end d-grid gap-2">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" style="width:100%; display:     
   block;">Sign-up</button>
</div>
```

Comment: No go Sir. It's not reflecting even if I put in gap-4.

Comment: Sorry about that @Ibanez1408 - Instead of `d-grid`, try `.d-md-block` (naturally this will change the button width at the MD breakpoint so `d-sm-block` might wortk better for you). Point is, you can make different widths at different breakpoints. Here the Docs (down the page a little bit) https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/

Comment: In the bootstrap page, I can actually see it expand as soon as it reaches a certain point. But in my case, it isn't I event used this one. `<div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
            <button class="btn btn-primary me-md-2" type="button">Button</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
        </div>`

Comment: I edited my question to reflect the whole html.

Comment: OK, on the Div which houses the button (not the button itself) Try 'd-flex` on it's own :)